# I need help working with a variable

Tags: php, string, variables, string-parsing

I'm so sorry for my English I'll improve it I promise.

I'm using PHP and I have this: $var = 'word1-word2-word3-34567';

I just want to get whatever that is at the right of last dash, in this case '34567'.

Thank you!

Comment: Ever considered naming the language?

Comment: Please update the title so the question will be useful to future visitors. Otherwise it may be closed as too localized.

Answer (score 2):

Let's guess it's php:

```
array_pop(explode('-',$var))
```

or

```
substr($var,strrpos($var,'-')+1)
```

Comment: +1 array_pop was clever, haha. although I would go with the second one for micro-performance freakiness

Comment: @hugo_leonardo, whatever pleases you, there's more than one road to Rome :)

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$words = explode('-', 'word1-word2-word3-34567');
$last_word = $words[count($words) - 1];
```